# Is it possible for somebody to copyright a route on a map?

Tags: copyright

The Tour de France makes it quite difficult to get good map data about their stages. They publish some low-res images (possibly for purchase by media, I'm unsure). There is no modern 'navigable' map, like Google Maps.

If I can see the route on the maps they've published, does making a new map displaying the route infringe a copyright? I understand the image of the maps themselves are copyright, but what about the route path on public roads?

Comment: Do you want to make a map of the cyclists' position every X minutes/stages, or do you want just a map of the Tour de France path?

Comment: In what country? In the U.S. a route is not subject matter for a copyright.

Comment: @A.Darwin not every minute, just the path they'll be taking this year.

Comment: @user3344003 I live in Australia, but this is for a world-wide website...I find the international bit particularly interesting in this instance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Australia, there is no copyright in data.

[IceTV Pty Ltd v Nine Network Australia Pty Ltd [2009] HCA 14](http://www.austlii.edu.au/cgi-bin/sinodisp/au/cases/cth/HCA/2009/14.html) concerned a defendant who copied TV guide data (what shows are on when) from newspapers/etc and re-published it on the Internet for its own profit. The plaintiff TV station was upset because they liked to sell this data. However, the plaintiff's copyright claim failed because copyright protects a particular expression, not information or data as such. There was no creative effort in the creation of the TV guide. It was just a list of facts.

Other jurisdictions may have protections for data e.g. EU Database Directive. I'm not familiar with those so I can't say whether they apply.

Another potential issue is any contract you entered into by visiting the Tour de France website which, without any need to rely on copyright, prohibits you from dealing in map route information. It would depend on the terms of service/etc and your jurisdiction's rules about the circumstances in which your courts will enforce that kind of thing (e.g. because it is excessive and unusual and was not brought to your attention).

Comment: Interesting. I hadn't considered the jurisdiction. I too live in Australia. The site I'm working on is hosted in the US, the race is in France. Who's laws do I have to abide by? that's probably rhetorical...

Comment: You could ask a separate question about relevant law for copyright. My basic understanding is that the copyright owner in France would have copyright under French law and, under a treaty with both the US and Australia (and every other country), those countries agree to treat foreign works the same as domestic works. So you would be sued under Australian or US law (depending on whether they go after you for damages or the server for an injunction) and that jurisdiction's copyright law would apply (not France's). If you ask a separate question, someone might be able to give a proper answer.